# Bevy Vertex Colored Shader

Tags: bevy

I'm a newbie to shaders, and I'm trying to build a vertex colored shader in Bevy. Fortunately one of the bevy examples goes through how to use a custom shader, and creates a vertex colored shader, but unfortunately it doesn't show lighting anymore! Here's the example for reference: https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/examples/shader/mesh_custom_attribute.rs

I want to use the custom attributes as shown in the example, but I still need lighting to work (properly shaded faces). Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: You might be able to replicate the [pbr shader](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/46cae5956f8535a7b24372fec4911704a942e8a4/crates/bevy_pbr/src/render_graph/pbr_pipeline/pbr.frag)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replicate the relevant parts from the PBR shader.
Take a look at my approach [here](https://github.com/janhohenheim/foxtrot/blob/v0.1.8/assets/shaders/repeated.wgsl#L42) for inspiration.